# How do I remove a list from an array of lists based on a condition using groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy and need help removing an entire list if it does not meet a criteria
Here is the JSON --

```
{
  "School" : New Elementary School,
  "District" : "District1",
  "City" : "NewTown",
     "Students" : [ {
     "Name": "Student1",
     "Grade": "1"    
    }, {
     "Name": "Student2",
     "Grade": "2"
    }, {
     "Name": "Student3",
     "Grade": "1"  
    }, {
     "Name": "Student4",
     "Grade": "1"  
    }, {
     "Name": "Student5",
     "Grade": "1"   
    } ],
}
```

I want a JSON which will have students from Grade 1 only i.e. remove Student2.
Output should be --

```
{
  "School" : New Elementary School,
  "District" : "District1",
  "City" : "NewTown",
     "Students" : [ {
     "Name": "Student1",
     "Grade": "1"    
    },  {
     "Name": "Student3",
     "Grade": "1"  
    }, {
     "Name": "Student4",
     "Grade": "1"  
    }, {
     "Name": "Student5",
     "Grade": "1"   
    } ],
}
```

I have the loop in place and the condition as well. I looked up online to removing an entire list but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how it failed, so we can improve on it.  The functional way to remove from a list is to `findAll` with the complement of your predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **removeAll** function to do that. Example

```
List a = [[a:1],[a:2],[a:1]]
a.removeAll{ it.a==2 }
print(a)
[[a:1], [a:1]]
```

In your case

```
students = students.removeAll{ it.Grade == "2" }
```